# How can I apply groupBy but use a different value as my key?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, date, angularjs-ng-repeat

I my HTML code is shown below:

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="panel columns small-12" ng-repeat="(key, value) in rse| groupBy: 'unixTime'">
      <h5>{{key}}</h5>
      <li ng-repeat="se in value">
        {{se.name}} ({{se.times}} times)
      </li>
  </div>
</div>
```

The group by is provided by: https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter

The the data it will be provided is a list of json objects example shown below:

```
[
    {
        "name": "test",
        "unixTime": "1422748800",
        "uiTime": "Monday 6th December 2015",
        "times": "1"
    },
    {
        "name": "test",
        "unixTime": "1423094400",
        "uiTime": "Tuesday 1th December 2015",
        "times": "1"
    },
    {
        "name": "test",
        "unixTime": "1423267200",
        "uiTime": "Wednesday 2th December 2015",
        "times": "1"
    }
]
```

The issue I am facing is when grouping my UNIX time which is MS since epoch I get the time in the correct order which I require but then I cannnot show the user friendly date within the H5 tag I then have to show it within the LI repeat which means the date would be shown more than once.

If I then change the group by time to "uiTime" instead which is the user friendly version of ms since epoch it displays them in the wrong order e.g. alphabetical order showing "Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday" which is clearly the wrong order.

How can I group by but use a different value as my key or even convert the ms from epoch to my nice UI friendly date string within the view (I know this is a bad practice as I do this in my service layer and using services in views are BAD).

Hope someone can help.
Thanks

Comment: `groupBy` - Is this something that you created. Afaik, Angularjs standard does not have a groupBy filter. If you have created it, can you post its code?

Comment: Hi, Sorry for that this has been updated within the question: https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter

Comment: I see 2 incorrect usages here. The first is `(key,value)` when you iterate over an array (it should be used when iterating on objects), and the 2nd is that you iterate over the value from the first `ng-repeat`, which is an object, and actually that should be iterated over using `(key,value)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="panel columns small-12" ng-repeat="(key, value) in rse| groupBy: 'unixTime'">
      <h5>{{value[0].uiTime}}</h5>
      <li ng-repeat="se in value">
        {{se.name}} ({{se.times}} times)
      </li>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's great and works perfect. I actually can't belive I never thought of that for some reason I had in my head I could use value before the ng-repear LI part.